# Get the difference on each date and insert into database

Tags: c#, database, ado.net

I have a table with a (IDcolumn, int), (Differencecolumn, int) and (Datecolumn DateTime)  that contains different dates.

And a method that compute the difference between the dates that ignores the weekends.

```
    public static double GetBusinessDays(DateTime startD, DateTime endD)
    {
        double calcBusinessDays =
            1 + ((endD - startD).TotalDays * 5 -
            (startD.DayOfWeek - endD.DayOfWeek) * 2) / 7;

        if ((int)endD.DayOfWeek == 6) calcBusinessDays--;
        if ((int)startD.DayOfWeek == 0) calcBusinessDays--;

        return calcBusinessDays;
    }
```

I want to get each GetBusinessDays value on each Datecolumn from date today.
And insert it to each corresponding Differencecolumn.

For example

```
ID  Date        Difference
1   4-22-2013
2   4-23-2013
3   4-24-2013
```

Assume that the date today is 4-28-2013. The difference must contain 6, 5, 4 respectively.

This what i have done for now but it not works :(

```
        myDatabaseConnection.OpenConnection();
        mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        mySqlCommand.CommandText = "select * from Table1 where Difference IS Null";
        SqlDataReader sqlreader = mySqlCommand2.ExecuteReader();

        int i;

        while (sqlreader.Read())
        {
            i = sqlreader.GetInt32(0);
            double y = GetBusinessDays(sqlreader.GetDateTime(1), DateTime.Now);
            string commandtext = "Update Table1 SET Difference = " + y + " Where ID = " + i + " ";
            mySqlCommand.CommandText = " " + commandtext + " ";
        }
        myDatabaseConnection.CloseConnection();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, you appear to be missing a call to `mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`.  That should go inside your `while` loop, after you assign to `mySqlCommand.CommandText`.

You'll also need to use a separate `SqlCommand` object for the Update query, as the [existing one is being used](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317559) by the `SqlDataReader` as you iterate through the result set.  I also recommend *always* using [parameterized SQL](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).  Putting these two points together:

```
SqlCommand myUpdateCmd = new SqlCommand("Update [Table1] SET [Difference] = @Difference Where [ID] = @ID", myDatabaseConnection);
myUpdateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", i);
myUpdateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Difference", (int)y);
myUpdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Beyond that, here are some suggestions that you may find helpful:

You seem to be assuming that the Difference column will initially be NULL, but you didn't show the exact definition for Table1.  Make sure the Difference column allows NULL values, and that there is no default value set (or that the default value is NULL).

To guarantee that the columns are in the order you expect, I recommend doing one of the following.

1. Specify the column names in your `select` query:

   ```
   select [id], [date], [difference] from [Table1] where [difference] is null
   ```
2. When retrieving a column's value through the `SqlDataReader`, don't hard-code the column's ordinal (0, 1, 2, ...).  Instead, use the `GetOrdinal()` method to dynamically determine the column's ordinal. For example:

   ```
   i = sqlreader.GetInt32(sqlreader.GetOrdinal("id"));
   ```

Almost all of these ADO.NET objects are `IDisposable`.  As such, it's generally best to make use of C#'s `using` statement to guarantee that these objects will be cleaned up.

```
using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    // code that uses myDatabaseConnection goes here
}
```

Putting all of these points together, we end up with:

```
using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection("DB connection string goes here"))
{
    myDatabaseConnection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select [id], [difference], [date] from [Table1] where [difference] is null", myDatabaseConnection))
    using (SqlDataReader sqlreader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
    using (SqlCommand myUpdateCmd = new SqlCommand("update [Table1] set [difference] = @difference where [id] = @id", myDatabaseConnection))
    {
        int i;

        myUpdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
        myUpdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@difference", SqlDbType.Int);

        while (sqlreader.Read())
        {
            i = sqlreader.GetInt32(sqlreader.GetOrdinal("id"));
            double y = GetBusinessDays(sqlreader.GetDateTime(sqlreader.GetOrdinal("date")), DateTime.Now);
            myUpdateCmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = i;
            myUpdateCmd.Parameters["@difference"].Value = (int)y;
            myUpdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Update: Karlx mentioned that he had to enable [Multiple Active Result Sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx) on the database connection before his application would work.  To do this, add "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" to your database connection string.

Comment: Ok i'll try this. Is it alright to not close the databaseConnection?

Comment: As long as your database connection object implements the IDisposable interface (SqlConnection does) then it will be closed for you when execution reaches the end of the `using` block - in this case, the outermost using block.

Comment: Error "There is already an open DataReader associate with this Command which must be closed first". I add sqlreader.close before the executenotquery only 1 row is update and got Error "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.

Comment: That would be why I said "You'll also need to use a separate SqlCommand object for the Update query, as the existing one is being used by the SqlDataReader". Notice that in my complete example code (at the bottom) I am using myUpdateCmd.

Comment: "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" must be added to ConnectionString to make it work :) . Thank you so much David :)

Comment: Doh! Thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit the answer to include that.